# What is the difference between mutually independent and pairwise independent events in probability theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let us assume that a number is selected at random from $1, 2, 3$.
We define

$$A = \{1, 2\},\quad B = \{2, 3\},\quad C = \{1, 3\}$$

Then are $A$, $B$ and $C$ **mutually independent** or **pairwise independent** or both?

I am confused between **mutually** vs **pairwise** independent.

Comment: Check [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/41) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Pairwise_and_mutual_independence).

Comment: You can also read my answer [here]( https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3576328/351322). Hope that helps.

Comment: Your question has omitted the one alternative that turns out to be correct—namely that the events $\ A$, $\ B,$ and $\ C\  $ are *neither* mutually independent *nor* pairwise independent,  since \begin{align} P(A\cap B)&=P(\{2\})\\&=\frac{1}{3}\ ,\ \text{but}\\ P(A)P(B)&=\Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)\Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)\\&=\frac{4}{9}\\&\ne P(A\cap B)\ .\end{align}

Comment: What does the event $A$ mean?

Comment: You really should have defined "at random" here.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Mutual independence**: Every event is independent of any intersection of the other events.

**Pairwise independence**: Any two events are independent.

$A, B, C$ are mutually independent if $$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$$ $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$ $$P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C)$$ $$P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)$$

On the other hand, $A, B, C$ are pairwise independent if $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$ $$P(A\cap C)=P(A)P(C)$$ $$P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C)$$

I'm sure you can solve your problem now.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I think these are pairwise independent but not mutually independent?

Comment: What is your $P(A\cap B)$ and what are your $P(A)$ and $P(B)$?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the event $A$?

Comment: Question says `'Define A={1, 2}'`. I assume it means A is an event that **either 1 or 2 is selected**.

Comment: If that is so, calculate the probabilities and verify. By the way, $A\cap B$ means the event that $A$ happens and $B$ happens, just to be clear.

Comment: Ohh Okay. So then P(A)*P(B) is 4/9 and P(A-intersect-B) is 1/3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45155/discussion-between-sangram-and-jdf).

Comment: Jus to add, mutual independence as seen above is a harder claim and implies pairwise indolence but it is not so the other way round.

Answer (score 5):

Pairwise Independent Conditions:

1. P(AB) = P(A)P(B)
2. P(BC) = P(B)P(C)
3. P(AC) = P(A)P(C)

Mutual Independent Conditions:

1. P(AB) = P(A)P(B)
2. P(BC) = P(B)P(C)
3. P(AC) = P(A)P(C)
4. P(ABC) = P(A)P(B)P(C)

Let us take an example to understand the situation clearly.

A lot contains 50 defective and 50 non-defective pens.
Two pens are drawn at random, one at a time, with
replacement. The events A, B, C are defined as :

- A = ( the first  pen is defective)
- B = (the second  pen is non-defective)
- C = (the two pens are both defective or both non-defective).

Determine whether:

- (i) A, B, C are pairwise independent.
- (ii) A, B, C are independent. [IIT 1992]

Solution :

- D := Defective , N := Not Defective
- P(A) = P{the first pen is defective} = P($[D_{1}D_{2},D_{1}N_{2}] ) = (\frac{1}{2})^2 + (\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{2}$
- P(B) = P{the second pen is non-defective} = P($D_{1}N_{2},N_{1}N_{2}$) = $\frac{1}{2}$
- P(C) = P{the two pens are both defective OR not defective} = P($D_{1}D_{2},N_{1}N_{2}$) = $\frac{1}{2}$

Then P($A\bigcap B$) = P(AB) = P($D_{1}N_{2}$) = $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$=$\frac{1}{4}$, P(AC)=P($D_{1}D_{2}$) = $\frac{1}{4}$ , P(BC)= P($N_{1}N_{2}$) = $\frac{1}{4}$.

But, P($A\bigcap B\bigcap C) = P(ABC) = \varnothing = null$ = no  common elements = $0$.

Therefore, $P(AB) = P(BC) = P(AC) = \frac{1}{4}$. But $P(ABC) = 0 \neq P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(C)$.

Hence,  A, B, C are pairwise independent BUT Not Mutually Independent.