# When prove P(A ∩ B | C) is P(A | C)⋅P(B | C) some place not understood

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have trouble understanding one last step of my proof process.
The problem is :

Let A,B,C be **mutual indenpendent** events, $P(C) > 0$ . Prove A, B are conditionally independent of C.

After translating to math language:

$$P(A \cap B | C) \Rightarrow  P(A|C) \cdot P(B|C) $$

My prove:

$$P(A \cap B | C) \\
= \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)} \\
= \frac{P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(C))}{P(C)} \\
= P(A)\cdot P(B)
$$

But I don't know how to interpret this as $P(A|C) \cdot P(B|C)$, Please help.

Comment: Do you mean that $A,B,C$ are pairwise independent or mutually independent?

Comment: I think it's ,, are pairwise independent so $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ can be $P(A)*P(B)*P(C)$

Comment: $P(A∩B∩C) =P(A)P(B)P(C)$ is not what pairwise independence means.  Note your $\Rightarrow$s should be $=$.

Comment: Well, the claim is false if it is "pairwise" and true if it is "mutual".

Comment: I think you should review the definitions and basic properties.  "mutual" implies "pairwise" and pairwise implies, among other things, that $P(A\,|\,C)=P(A)$.  Should say:  it's not unusual for people to write "independent" as shorthand for "mutually independent" but I think it's a bad idea and that it often leads to misunderstandings.

Comment: Hi @lulu, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) is where I learn _Conditional_independence_ events, and [this](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_4_conditional_independence.php#eq18) I don't know what is pairwise or mutual.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920473/what-is-the-difference-between-mutually-independent-and-pairwise-independent-eve#:~:text=Mutual%20independence%3A%20Every%20event%20is,Any%20two%20events%20are%20independent.) is a relevant question.  You can find others.

Comment: @lulu, Thank you

Comment: Should say:  mutual implies pairwise as a matter of definition.  "mutual" means that any combination of events taken from the relevant collection is independent.

Comment: But still don't understand why ()⋅() = (|)⋅(|)

Comment: Try proving that if $A$ and $C$ are mutually independent then $P(A)=P(A\mid C).$ The proof is similar to what you've already done.

Comment: If they are all pairwise independent you can say  $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ and $P(A \mid C)=P(A)$ and $P(B \mid C)=P(B)$.  If they are mutually independent then you can say that and also say  $P(A\cap B \mid C)=P(A \cap B)$